# Laravel : Form select option value is always NULL when submitting

Tags: php, laravel, forms, html-select

I have a form where I put de id's of my bands table inside a select option. When I select an id in the dropdownlist and try to submit the form, the value always remains NULL. How can I retrieve the value I selected?

create.blade.php file :

```
<form>
    <select name="band_id">
        @foreach ($bands as $band) 
            <option value="{{ $band->band_id }}">{{ $band->band_id }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

My Bandcontroller inside my store action :

```
$bands->band_id = $input['band_id'];
```

Comment: I think you are using Input in a wrong way, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31696723/11264760) Or just use `$request` variable.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are using `@foreach ($band as $band)`, make sure it's not a typo and if not then fix it (Could be `$bands as $band` and assumed you know what I mean). Anyways, you may also try this:

```
{{ Form::select('band_id', $bands, Input::old('band_id')) }}
```

Just pass the `$bands` variable to the `View` and `Laravel` will create the `SELECT` for you, you don't need to loop manually. To retrieve the value, you may try this:

```
$band_id = Input::get('band_id');
```

Comment: It loads all the fields of the table bands in the dropdown at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 6 or above

```
//blade
{!!Form::open(['action'=>'CategoryController@storecat', 'method'=>'POST']) !!}
        <div class="form-group">
            <select name="cat" id="cat" class="form-control input-lg">
                <option value="">Select App</option>
                @foreach ($cats as $cat)
                <option value={{$cat->id}}>{{ $cat->title }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="from-group">
            {{Form::label('name','Category name:')}}
            {{Form::text('name','',['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Category name'])}}
        </div>
    <br>
    {!!Form::submit('Submit', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])!!}
    {!!Form::close()!!}

// controller 
  public function storecat(Request $request){
        Log::channel('stack')->info('name'.$request->app);
        if($request->input('cat')==null){ // retriving option value by the name attribute of select tag
            return redirect(route('cats.cat'))->with('error', 'Select an app');
        }
        $this->validate($request,[
            'name'=>'required',
        ]);

    }
```