# laravel 5 : Class 'input' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

In my `routes.php` file I have :

```
Route::get('/', function () {

    return view('login');
});

Route::get('/index', function(){
    return view('index');
});

Route::get('/register', function(){
    return view('register');
});
Route::post('/register',function(){

    $user = new \App\User;
    $user->username = input::get('username');
    $user->email  = input::get('email');
    $user->password = Hash::make(input::get('username'));
    $user->designation = input::get('designation');
    $user->save();

});
```

I have a form for users registration. I am also taking the form inputs value in the `routes.php`.

But the error comes up when I register a user .
Error:

```
FatalErrorException in routes.php line 61:
Class 'input' not found
```

Answer (score 284, accepted):

It is `Input` and not `input`.
[This commit](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/2adbbbd91e9d6e2d569cc56f138b7273efe25651) removed `Input` facade definition from `config/app.php` hence you have to manually add that in to `aliases` array as below,

```
'Input' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class,
```

Or You can import `Input` facade directly as required,

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
```

Comment: What if I use laravelcollective for the forms in laravel 5.2 and I use {{ Form }} in a view, not in routes as Shafee does.  
`{{ Form::text('name', Input::old('name'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}`

Comment: You can use \Input to access it globally

Comment: How or where do I need to put this? Changing Input to \Input (inside the form tags) does not work.. ***Also*** I am not using illuminate\support\facades.. but `"laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*"`

Comment: Sorry I did not pay attention to your earlier comment but in HTML you can use helper function old() which is nothing but wrapper for Input::old()

Comment: @NicolasV you can put it under `aliases` inside `config/app.php`, as [Nvan's answer points out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35023801/309031).

Comment: `Input` is replaced with laravel 5.2 `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

Answer (score 33):

For laravel `<` **5.2**:

Open `config/app.php` and add the `Input` class to `aliases`:

```
'aliases' => [
// ...
  'Input' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class,
// ...
],
```

---

For laravel `>=` **5.2**

Change `Input::` to `Request::`

Answer (score 28):

In Laravel 5.2 Input:: is replaced with Request::

use

```
Request::
```

Add to the top of Controller or any other Class

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Answer (score 27):

You can add a facade in your `folder\config\app.php`

```
'Input' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class,
```

Answer (score 5):

In first your problem is about the spelling of the input class, should be Input instead of input. And you have to import the class with the good namespace.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
```

If you want it called 'input' not 'Input', add this :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input as input;
```

Second, It's a dirty way to store into the database via route.php,
and you're not processing data validation.
If a sent parameter isn't what you expected, maybe an SQL error will appear, its caused by the data type.
You should use controller to interact with information and store via the model in the controller method.

The route.php file handles routing.
It is designed to make the link between the controller and the asked route.

To learn about controller, middleware, model, service ... 
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/

If you need some more information, solution about problem you can join the community : https://laracasts.com/

Regards.

Answer (score 5):

if You use Laravel version 5.2 Review this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#accessing-the-request

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;//Access able for All requests
...

class myController extends Controller{
   public function myfunction(Request $request){
     $name = $request->input('username');
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

**In larvel => 6 Version:**

Input no longer exists In larvel 6,7,8 Version. Use `Request` instead of `Input`.

**Based on the Laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade#the-input-facade), since version 6.x Input has been removed.**

**The Input Facade**

*Likelihood Of Impact: Medium*

> The `Input` facade, which was primarily a duplicate of the `Request`
> facade, has been removed. If you are using the `Input::get` method, you
> should now call the `Request::input` method. All other calls to the
> Input facade may simply be updated to use the `Request` facade.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
..
..
..
 public function functionName(Request $request)
    {
        $searchInput = $request->q;
}
```

Comment: You've mixed up the Request classes. For `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request` you can use `Request::input`, but if you want the method type hint in `Request $request` it's `Illuminate\Http\Request`

Answer (score 4):

Declaration in config/app.php under aliases:-

```
'Input' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class,
```

Or You can import Input facade directly as required,

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
```

or

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input as input;
```

Answer (score 2):

`'Input' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class`, add it to App.php.

Answer (score 1):

This clean code snippet works fine for me:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
Route::post('/register',function(Request $request){

   $user = new \App\User;
   $user->username = $request->input('username');
   $user->email  = $request->input('email');
   $user->password = Hash::make($request->input('username'));
   $user->designation = $request->input('designation');
   $user->save();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in config/app.php under aliases:-

```
'Input' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class,
```

Answer (score 0):

Miscall of Class it should be `Input` not `input`

Answer (score 0):

It's changed in laravel 6. [See for more info here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade#the-input-facade)

Don't do anything in app.php and anywhere else, just replace

input::get()  with   Request::input()

and

on top where you declare Input,Validator,Hash etc., remove **Input** and add **Request**

use something like :

Config,DB,File,Hash,**Input**,Redirect,Session,View,Validator,**Request**;

Answer (score 0):

```
   #config/app.php
   'aliases' => [
        ...
        'Input' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class,
        ...
    ],

   #Use Controller file
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
   ==OR==
   use Input;
```

Read full example: https://devnote.in/laravel-class-input-not-found