# file upload error in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

This is my upload.blade.php code

```
{!!Form::open(array('url'=>'parser','method'=>'POST','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data','onsubmit'=>'return validate(this)', 'files'=>true)) !!}
                <div class="panel panel-default file-upload">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <label for="exampleInputFile">Upload Manually :</label>
                     </div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    {!! Form::file('Filename') !!}
             <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" width="100%">
          </progress>
    <h3 id="status"></h3>
    <p id="loaded_n_total"></p>
    {!! Form::submit('Submit', array('class'=>'btn btn-info','value'=>'Upload File')) !!}
          {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Then i am having a controller class to move uploaded file, the upload function is

```
public function uploadFile(){

     $a=session('upload');
      $path="/logparser/html/upload/".$a;
            $fileExistsFlag = 0;
     $file = array('Filename' => Request::file('Filename'));
             if(!(is_dir($path))){
              mkdir($path, 0777);
              chmod($path,0777); 
              }

             Request::file('Filename')->move($path);

             Session::flash('success', 'Upload successfully');
             return view('dash');
  }
```

It is giving an error: Call to a member function move() on null
And i looked at the contents of file but the array was empty.

Comment: Is dd($request::file('Filename'); also empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved the problem just by making changes into the php.ini file.
I have changed the "upload_max_filesize=-1" and "post_max_size=-1".

Answer (score 3):

I use this function for uploading image and it is working fine -

```
 public function upload_image(){

    $input = Input::instance();
    $destinationPath = public_path("uploads/user");

   if($input->file('user_image')){

    try{
        if ($input->file('user_image')->isValid())
        {
             $extension = $input->file('user_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
             $fileName = rand(11111, 99999) . '.' . $extension;
             if($input->file('user_image')->move($destinationPath, $fileName)){
            // Updating user image in db

            }else{
                $this->data['message'] = Lang::get('messages.image_upload_fail');
                 $this->utilObj->renderJson('error', $this->data);
            }
        }else{
            $this->data['message'] = Lang::get('messages.image_upload_fail');
            $this->utilObj->renderJson('error', $this->data);
        }
    }
    catch (\Exception $e) {

        Log::error("AppUsers::upload_image()  " . $e->getMessage());
        $this->data['message'] = Lang::get('messages.image_upload_fail');
        $this->utilObj->renderJson('error', $this->data);
        return false;
    }
   }else{

        $this->data['message'] =  Lang::get('messages.image_required');
        $this->utilObj->renderJson('error', $this->data);
        return false;
   }

}
```

Comment: You can include input see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31696679/laravel-5-class-input-not-found

Comment: Again it is coming null.... somehow the values are not coming to the controller function.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
$file=Input::file('Filename')->getClientOriginalName();
Input::file('Filename')->move($destination,$file);
```

Comment: Error :Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null

Comment: Maybe you have problem with your javascript function onsubmit, or your validation does not allow file to pass to controller. Try without onsubmit function.

Comment: Try adding:

    uploadFile(Request $request){
    dd ($request->file('Filename')); or even dd($request->input());

If thats not working, you are having problem in ur script or form

Answer (score 0):

You can write code like this

```
public function uploadFile(Illuminate\Http\Request $request){
      $a=session('upload');
      $path="/logparser/html/upload/".$a;
      $fileExistsFlag = 0;

      if(!(is_dir($path))){
        mkdir($path, 0777);
        chmod($path,0777); 
      }

      $request->file('Filename')->move($path);
      Session::flash('success', 'Upload successfully');
     return view('dash');
}
```

For more information you can read document of laravel 5.2
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#files