# Fatal error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Input' not found when sending a form

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I'm trying to send an email filled with a form from a Laravel app.

When you hit submit it throws the above error:

> Fatal error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Input' not found

Not sure why as I don't have, nor knew I needed to have an Input controller, or what I would put in it.

Below is the content of the controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class contact extends Controller
{
     // This function will show the view
    public function showForm()
    {
        return view('pages.contact');
    }

     public function handleFormPost()
     {
         $input = Input::only('name', 'email', 'msg');

         $validator = Validator::make($input,
             array(
                 'name' => 'required',
                 'email' => 'required|email',
                 'msg' => 'required',
             )
         );

         if ($validator->fails())
         {
             return Redirect::to('contact')->with('errors', $validator->messages());
         } else { // the validation has not failed, it has passed


            // Send the email with the contactemail view, the user input
            Mail::send('contactemail', $input, function($message)
            {
                 $message->from('idocompscihw@gmail.com', 'Your Name');

                 $message->to('idocompscihw@gmail.com');
             });

             // Specify a route to go to after the message is sent to provide the user feedback
             return Redirect::to('thanks');
         }

     }
 }
```

Below is the view of the forum (based on bootstrap):

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>A basic contact form</h1>
    <form id="contact" method="post" class="form" role="form">

        @if(Session::has('errors'))
            <div class="alert alert-warning">
                @foreach(Session::get('errors')->all() as $error_message)
                    <p>{{ $error_message }}</p>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        @endif

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 form-group">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text"autofocus="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="msg" placeholder="Message" rows="5"></textarea>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel 5 : Class 'input' not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31696679/laravel-5-class-input-not-found)

Answer (score 9):

Used this in your contact.php Controllers-

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
```

your error will get fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Input:: is replaced with Request::. Instead of

```
$input = Input::only('name', 'email', 'msg');
```

use this:

```
$input = Request::only('name', 'email', 'msg');
```

And if you get error something about 'should not use statically' just add this at the top of your file

```
use Request;
```

If you already have this line:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

delete it because you can't have two classes with the same name in one file

Answer (score 2):

```
public function handleFormPost(Request $request)
{
    $name = $request->get('name');
    $email = $request->get('email');
    $msg = $request->get('msg');   
}
```

OR

```
public function handleFormPost(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you not use input try this :

```
use Input;
```

Put it after the namespace declaration like this

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers; 
use Input;
...

?>
```

Comment: where would I put that?

Comment: <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Input;

Comment: `Error
Class 'Input' not found `