# Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input' not found

Tags: laravel, class

I have an error when upgrading laravel 6

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError
>   (E_ERROR) Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input' not found

**Source code:**

[image]

**ERROR:**

[image]

**can you help to fix my code?**

Comment: Please make a [mcve] (including posting the necessary source in plaintext)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

if you're using less version of **Laravel 5.2**

In `config/app.php`, replace:

```
'Input' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class,
```

Or You can import `Input` facade directly as required,

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
```

In **Laravel 5.2** Input:: is replaced with Request::

use

```
Request::
```

Add to the top of Controller or any other Class

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

**In your case**

```
$image_tmp = $request->image;
$fileName = time() . '.'.$image_tmp->clientExtension();
```

**Laravel 6X**
The `Input` facade, which was primarily a duplicate of the `Request` facade, has been removed. If you are using the `Input::get` method, you should now call the `Request::input` method. All other calls to the Input facade may simply be updated to use the `Request` facade.

You can directly use $request as well

```
$request->all();
```

Comment: The Input facade was removed in Laravel 6.x: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade#the-input-facade

Comment: The answer posted while ago. so, I didn't notice on this answer. Thanks I've updated.

Answer (score 22):

In `config/app.php`, replace:

```
'Input' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class
```

with

```
'Input' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
```

Comment: This works better if you are migrating an old Laraval 5 App to Laravel 6+.

Answer (score 7):

I have resolved below it worked for me

**Step 1**: Access the link: **yourproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades**

**Step 2**: Create a file with the file name: **Input.php**

**Step 3**: Paste the code below into the file you just created and save

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Support\Facades;

/**
 * @method static \Illuminate\Http\Request instance()
 * @method static string method()
 * @method static string root()
 * @method static string url()
 * @method static string fullUrl()
 * @method static string fullUrlWithQuery(array $query)
 * @method static string path()
 * @method static string decodedPath()
 * @method static string|null segment(int $index, string|null $default = null)
 * @method static array segments()
 * @method static bool is(...$patterns)
 * @method static bool routeIs(...$patterns)
 * @method static bool fullUrlIs(...$patterns)
 * @method static bool ajax()
 * @method static bool pjax()
 * @method static bool secure()
 * @method static string ip()
 * @method static array ips()
 * @method static string userAgent()
 * @method static \Illuminate\Http\Request merge(array $input)
 * @method static \Illuminate\Http\Request replace(array $input)
 * @method static \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag|mixed json(string $key = null, $default = null)
 * @method static \Illuminate\Session\Store session()
 * @method static \Illuminate\Session\Store|null getSession()
 * @method static void setLaravelSession(\Illuminate\Contracts\Session\Session $session)
 * @method static mixed user(string|null $guard = null)
 * @method static \Illuminate\Routing\Route|object|string route(string|null $param = null)
 * @method static string fingerprint()
 * @method static \Illuminate\Http\Request setJson(\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag $json)
 * @method static \Closure getUserResolver()
 * @method static \Illuminate\Http\Request setUserResolver(\Closure $callback)
 * @method static \Closure getRouteResolver()
 * @method static \Illuminate\Http\Request setRouteResolver(\Closure $callback)
 * @method static array toArray()
 * @method static bool offsetExists(string $offset)
 * @method static mixed offsetGet(string $offset)
 * @method static void offsetSet(string $offset, $value)
 * @method static void offsetUnset(string $offset)
 *
 * @see \Illuminate\Http\Request
 */
class Input extends Facade
{
    /**
     * Get an item from the input data.
     *
     * This method is used for all request verbs (GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE)
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  mixed   $default
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function get($key = null, $default = null)
    {
        return static::$app['request']->input($key, $default);
    }

    /**
     * Get the registered name of the component.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'request';
    }
}
```

**Step 4**: Rerun your project

Done.Good luck!

Comment: Good Solution !

Answer (score 5):

You probably update your laravel package. And `Input::` is replaced in laravel 5.2 and above. You can replace your input in `config/app.php` with

`'Input' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class,`

and in your controller, you can reference it like this

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request as Input;
```

Answer (score 4):

In **Laravel 5.2** `Input::` is replaced with `Request::`

use

`Request::`

Add to the top of Controller or any other Class

`use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37203477/12089073

Answer (score 3):

Input no longer exists. Either use the Request facade or alias that instead of Input.
Kindly read this upgrade guide in Laravel 6 for more details. 
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade#the-input-facade

Answer (score 2):

The use of Input whether as namespace or in config/app.php became obsolete in Laravel 8.
You have to use Illuminate\Http\Request; in your namespace instead. And you get the Input from request. Below is the API.

```
Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function index(Request $request){
   $id = $request->Input('id');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$request->all()` in place of `Input::all()`. It worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

$image_tmp = $request->image;
$fileName = time() . '.'.$image_tmp->clientExtension()

Answer (score 0):

`use Input;` add to the top of your class.

Answer (score 0):

The very best way to fix this is to copy the **Input.php** file which laravel provided [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Input.php)
and paste the file in your project directory.

Don't forget to add this to your controller **use Illuminate\Http\Request;**

> laravelproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades

Answer (score 0):

You can use the global `request()` function e.g `request('key')` for accessing individual keys or
`request()->all()` to access all request data.

Answer (score -1):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;

Request::input();
```