# AJAX call returning `Internal Server Error 500` after upgrading Laravel to 6

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-6

I upgraded my Laravel project from version `5.8` to `6` and some ajax calls are now broken. I'm attaching the screenshot of the error I'm facing related to ajax call using jquery below.

[image: Error in console]

My hunch is that it's not related to csrf token because I've excluded these requests from VerifyCsrfToken middleware (using except array) code below:

```
protected $except = [
  '/get-post-data',
  '/get-post-count',
  '/get-post-data',
];
```

Php version: 7.2.34 
OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Could you please help me to solve this error? I can also provide more information if required. Thanks a thousand times.

### Solution is given in comments by [iamab-in](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6274211/iamab-in) and link to answer is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58078757/class-illuminate-support-facades-input-not-found/58079332#58079332)

Comment: what does the exception says? check `dd($exception)` result from your `catch` block or `Handler.php`

Comment: I added dd() and code is looking like (in Handler.php)
```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        dd($e);
        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
```
It returned [image](https://imgur.com/a/XRQ8p4M)

Comment: check `Network` tab in the browser developer options.

Comment: In `Network` tab I got [this error](https://imgur.com/0SVJuHz) @iamab.in

Comment: `'Class Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input' Not found In BrowseController.php` is the issue. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58079332/6274211) SO answer.

Comment: It worked. I'm so much Thankful to you bro. Even I can't explain. Just Thank you soo much bro :pray [You shared solution helped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58078757/class-illuminate-support-facades-input-not-found/58079332#58079332)