# Error Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input' not found laravel v6.0.2

Tags: laravel-6

I have added following line in app.php in alias section and have used in controll as "use input"

```
'Input' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class,
```

still it gives error input class not found

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbSBa.png)

Comment: follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31696679/laravel-5-class-input-not-found

Answer (score 2):

`Input` no longer exists. Use `Request` instead of `Input`.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
```