# Search jobs in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need to make search form in Laravel

This is code ***welcome.blade.php***:

```
<form action="/search" method="POST" role="search">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q"
               placeholder="Search job"> <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
<div class="container">
    @if(isset($details))
        <div class="row">
            @foreach( $details as $job)
                <h5>{{$job->company_name}}</h5>
                <h3>{{$job->job_name}}</h3>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    @endif
</div>
```

This is route in ***web.php***:

```
   Route::any('/search', function () {
    $q = Input::get('q');
    $job = Job::where('job_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
        ->orWhere('company_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
        ->get();
    if (count($job) > 0)
        return view('welcome')
            ->withDetails($job)
            ->withQuery($q);
    else
        return view('welcome')
            ->withMessage('No Details found. Try to search again !');
});
```

I am getting an error:

**Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Console\Input\Input::get()**

How I can fix it?

Also I would like to know, how could I first display all jobs, and after search only jobs that match?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [laravel 5 : Class 'input' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31696679/laravel-5-class-input-not-found)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code the Class `Input` refers **wrong** source `Symfony\Component\Console\Input\Input` which helps to read input from `terminal/console`.

You have to use `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input` to get input from `HTTP Request`.

**OR**

Use `Illuminate\Http\Request`

```
Route::any('/search', function (Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    $q = $request->get('q');
    ...
```

**OR**

```
Route::any('/search', function () {
    $q = \request('q'); // also uses Illuminate\Http\Request
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how I can display all jobs at first, and then after search display only jobs that match? Because at this time, before search my page is empty

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong `Input` class.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
```

Or you can simply use `request('q')`